# BeautifulSoup give me list empty

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

For whatever reason, I cannot seem to find a way to get the text between div or span elements to print. I want to create a list with some reviews.

```
import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=request.get('https://www.yelp.ie/biz/tesla-san-francisco?osq=Tesla=Dealership')
r.status_code
r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.findaAll(class_="lemon--div__373c0__1mboc margin-b2__373c0__abANL border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU")
reviews = []
for div in divs:
reviews.append(span.find('p').text,'\n')
```

results is `[]`

Comment: in last line wrong syntax ! find('p) => find('p')

Comment: Thank you , my misstake. But still doesn't work. i have tryed this 'results = soup.findAll(class_='lemon--span__373c0__3997G raw__373c0__3rcx7', attrs={'lang':'en'})     reviews = [result.text for result in results]' but the same problem

Comment: actually i don't know any things about BeautifullSoap , so my simple hint is to search how te get elements in right way

Comment: I think that what is going on here is that the page content is generated dynamically using JavaScript so you can see it in your browser that supports JS, but the bare page code does not contain the elements you are trying to access.
You can check it by viewing page source in browser (Ctrl+U in chrome) then search for the class. This does not exactly solve the problem, but maybe it will help you in further research as your code works just fine.

Comment: Also, span is never defined in the mve

Answer (score 0):

In the section of Review Highlights, 3 reviews are loaded via following urls. Under that I mentioned all reviews url.

```
import requests

#  section of Review Highlights
# urls = ["https://www.yelp.ie/biz/y0pllLqKVUQi2IkhYYf9ug/review_feed?hrid=WqGBt4VQfr1vvGzie-QjLw&rh_type=phrase&rh_ident=oliver&rl=en",
# "https://www.yelp.ie/biz/y0pllLqKVUQi2IkhYYf9ug/review_feed?hrid=nlmFH44VXXAmqnKAnm0P1A&rh_type=phrase&rh_ident=dublin",
# "https://www.yelp.ie/biz/y0pllLqKVUQi2IkhYYf9ug/review_feed?hrid=OD-NXvs88PBfRaLgXPZrRQ&rh_type=phrase&rh_ident=model_s"
#         ]

ALL the reviews down the page

urls = ["https://www.yelp.ie/biz/y0pllLqKVUQi2IkhYYf9ug/review_feed?rl=en&sort_by=relevance_desc&q=&start={}".format(i) for i in range(0,20)]

reviews = []
for url in urls:
    r=requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    reviews.append(data['reviews'][0]['comment']['text'])

print('length', len(reviews))
for review in reviews:
    print(review, '\n')
```

Comment: hope its help you.

Comment: I think you just got the reviews highlights. There are ALL the reviews down the page. I think the OP wants those.

Comment: How did you decide on `range` needs to be 20?

Comment: just wanted to collect 20 reviews. nothing else.

Comment: ..Oh! I see...I am really bad with Json :).

Comment: If you think its helpful. Please mark it as useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `selenium` since the content seems dynamically generated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/bin/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.yelp.ie/biz/tesla-san-francisco?osq=Tesla=Dealership')
sleep(5)
divs = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"wrap\"]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/section[2]/div[2]")
comments = divs.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')
reviews = []
for comment in comments:
    reviews.append(comment.text)

for review in reviews:
    print(review)
```

Output:-

```
Your trust is our top concern, so businesses can't pay to alter or remove their reviews. Learn more.



Today was delivery day and we were pretty excited to collect our car. When we arrived we proceeded upstairs where the magic happens.

Jessica H. and Alex were both helping other customers and we were third in line. Even though we waited less than 15 minutes we were told they'd be with us promptly and they thanked us for our patience and for waiting. They made us feel valued and the time passed quickly. When it was our turn, Jessica explained the process, walked us through the documents she'd prepared in advance of our arrival (and even colour coded to make everything both easy and efficient), and explained to us what to expect.

The place was spotless. We saw the staff wearing masks, cleaning surfaces and office supplies after every use and they even had separate cups for clean versus dirty pens. These folks have this down to a science.

Our car was ready for us and Alex gave us a mini-tutorial, asked if we needed help and was prepared to answer questions even though we had none. He addressed one of our concerns and as we finished up, Jessica stepped-in to help get us on our way.

Jessica and Alex were really very helpful and kind. We were struck with their efficiency, how quickly they worked together to move between customers and how gracious and empathetic they were with us and everyone we saw them interact with during our visit. Five star service for sure.

A special note: Jessica H. obviously has a talent for service. She was attentive, involved and compassionate with all the customers she assisted today. She should be commended for the finesse with which she juggles customers and to-dos.

We loved the experience today and it elevated the brand in our eyes and affirmed the reason we chose to own a Tesla
```

The reviews continue...